# displaying excel sheet in odoo 9

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-9

how to display report in excel format for multiple records in odoo 9.0 ?

In the below code, It displays only a single record but i want to display multiple records.
Python Code:-

```
def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, partners):
         for obj in partners:
                  sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("timesheet")
                  bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
                  sheet.write(1,1, obj.employee_id.name)
         for line in obj.timesheet_ids:

                                bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
                                sheet.write(1,2, line.date)
                                sheet.write(1,3, line.account_id.name)
                                sheet.write(1,4 , line.name)
                                sheet.write(1,5, line.unit_amount)
XML code:-

<data>
<openerp>

<report
    id="partner_xlsx"
    model="hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet"
    string="Timesheet Report"
    report_type="xlsx"
    name="hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet.xlsx"
    file="hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet.xlsx"
    attachment_use="False"
/>
</openerp>
</data>
```

So, I can i solve this problem. May i get some help on this problem please?``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code writes in a loop on the same position on the excel sheet

try
for index, line in enumerate(obj.timesheet_ids):
   sheet.write(index,2, line.date)
...

or

for index, obj in enumerate(partners):
   sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("timesheet"+str(index))